# Is there an equivalent to on-submit for paper-input?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, material-design

I'm excited to start playing with paper elements, but I'm having some problems with form element submissions. In the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
<polymer-element name="c2button-element">
<template>
  <paper-input value="{{myname}}" floatinglabel="true" label="enter your name" on-change="{{nameSubmitted}}"></paper-input>
</template>
<script type="application/dart">
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';


@CustomTag('c2button-element')
class C2Button extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String myname = "Simon";

  void nameSubmitted(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    print("Being called with event $e for $myname");
  }

  C2Button.created() : super.created();
  @override void attached() { super.enteredView(); }
  @override void detached() { super.leftView(); }
}
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

The behavior I want for the input is for pressing `enter` or blurring the input to call `nameSubmitted` every time. What's actually happening is, only after changing the value of `myname` (which is not that surprising, since I've registered to `on-change`), do I get an event to fire, but it fires **twice**! After changing `myname` from `Simon` to `Edwin` and pressing enter:

```
Being called with event Instance of 'CustomEvent' for Edwin
Being called with event Instance of 'Event' for Edwin
```

Do I need to do something else, like register `on-keypress` and filter for the enter key? My first attempt at this still suffers from a similar called-twice problem. The first time I press enter, `myname` still contains the old value, as though paper-input hasn't committed the new value yet - is this due to validation?

```
<paper-input value="{{myname}}" floatinglabel="true" label="enter your name" on-keypress="{{nameSubmitted}}"></paper-input>

void nameSubmitted(KeyboardEvent e, var detail, Node target) {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) {return;}
  print("Being called with event $e for $myname");
}
```

After changing to `Edwin` and pressing enter twice:

```
Being called with event Instance of 'KeyboardEvent' for Simon
Being called with event Instance of 'KeyboardEvent' for Edwin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is filtering on enter (as above) and changing my binding to [`inputValue`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input) instead of `value`:

```html
<paper-input inputValue="{{myname}}" floatinglabel="true" label="enter your name" on-keypress="{{nameSubmitted}}"></paper-input>
```

I'm not happy with this solution though (I lose out on the validation feature of paper elements) so I'm certainly open to better answers.